# Using angular with requirejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I have a plain JS class that uses require

```
//a.js
(function() {
    define(function() {
        var vaz = function(dependency){
            var myFact = function(){
              // doing a new Dependency();
             }
            return myFact;
        };

        return ['dependency',vaz];
    });

}());
```

Now I'm creating a angular module:

```
    define([<a.js>], function(A){
      var mod = angular.module('myMod');
      mod.factory("myFact", A);
      mod.run([function(){
        new A() // gives an error 'A is not a constructor' 
        new A[1]() //gives an error 'dependency is not a constructor' 
      }])
    })
```

This gives me an error saying a is not a constructor and as it is legacy code, I'm not allowed to modify the a.js.
Please help.

Comment: `A` is not defined in `mod.factory("myFact", A);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If dependency's prototype has the `constructor` property correctly set, This should work :

```
define([<a.js>], function(A){
      var mod = angular.module('myMod');
      mod.factory("myFact", A);
       mod.run(['$injector', function[function($injector){
        var dep = $injector.get("dependency");
        var new A[1](dep.constructor);
      }])
    })
```

But if that's not the case you won't be able to do that without modifying your legacy code. (maybe you could just set the constructor property on `dependency`'s prototype without much side-effect)

Comment: m trying to get a constructor, but m getting an array.. even if I try to give a[1] , a is inherited from a B class that also returns an array

Comment: "m trying to get a constructor, but m getting an array.." You can't get an array from `$injector.get("myFact")` except if myFact returns an array "even if I try to give a[1]" that's still not a string. And you will **never** get a constructor from `$injector.get`.

Comment: I understood that we would not get constructor from injector.get()..I modified the code...  I'm saying just doing the above is also not giving me any result.
I need help in creating a constructor with the similar setup.